Spring WebMvcLinkBuilder ignores method parameters as DTO
I use the combination of linkTo(methodOn()) to generate links to my endpoint which works fine as long as i have the RequestParams as separate method arguments. When i move them into an DTO (because there are many...) the linkt just get generated without any params...
The Endpoint:
@GetMapping("/search")
fun searchByIds(
    params: SearchIdsParameterDto
): ResponseEntity<SearchEntriesDto> {
   // some code...
}

The DTO:
data class SearchByIdsParameterDto(
  @RequestParam()
  var subIds: String,

  @RequestParam()
  @Min(0)
  var start: Int?,

  @RequestParam()
  @Min(1)
  var limit: Int? = 20,

): RepresentationModel<SearchByIdsParameterDto>()

And this is how i want to generate the link:
private fun searchLink(
  rel: LinkRelation,
  params: SearchParameter,
  start: Int,
  limit: Int
): Link {
  val link = linkTo(
               methodOn(SearchCtl::class.java)
                 .searchByIds(
               SearchByIdsParameterDto(
                 params.subIDs,
                 start,
                 limit
               )
             )
           ).withRel(rel)

  // other than "self" this method is used for pagination links (first, next etc)
  // these links are expanded as is to remove templates
  return when (rel) {
    SELF -> link
        else -> link.expand()
  }
}

With that, the link gets generated but without any parameters in it.
